# VBA If Not Or Statenent

Tags: vba, excel

I have `If Not` statement with 2 `or` but the code runs still like it is regular `If` statement. Moncol is an integer variable that equales 13 and the if statement should go to End If, and it is not. This code should delete columns just when `Moncol` not equals 12 or 13 or 14.

```
With NewPayWS
    If Not MonCol = 12 Or Not MonCol = 13 Or Not MonCol = 14 Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, lastcol - 1), .Cells(1, MonCol + 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
        .Range(.Cells(1, DataType + 1), .Cells(1, MonCol - 4)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Select Case` instead, when having multiple scenarios of `If` and `Else`, it's much easier to use, and read.

```
Select Case MonCol
    Case 12, 13, 14
        ' do nothing

    Case Else
        .Range(.Cells(1, lastcol - 1), .Cells(1, MonCol + 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
        .Range(.Cells(1, DataType + 1), .Cells(1, MonCol - 4)).EntireColumn.Delete

End Select
```

**Edit 1**: Following @Rory comments, you can also use `Case 12 To 14`, this may come handy especially for ranges with a lot of values, then you can use `Case 12 To 30`, etc.

Comment: FWIW you can also do `Case 12 to 14` for a continuous range

Answer (score 6):

Your current If statement will always result in True.

You can do:

```
With NewPayWS
    If Not (MonCol = 12 Or MonCol = 13 Or MonCol = 14) Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, lastcol - 1), .Cells(1, MonCol + 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
        .Range(.Cells(1, DataType + 1), .Cells(1, MonCol - 4)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Comment: To expand on this for the OP: `!A OR !B` is the same as writing `!(A AND B)`.  Since in this case `A` is `MonCol = 12` and `B` is `MonCol = 13`, they can never *both* be True (since `12 != 13`), so `A AND B` is always False, meaning `!(A AND B)` is always True.  Conversely, `!(A OR B)` can be rewritten as `!A AND !B`, which is what I assume you were probably aiming for

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to handle it. Here's one more

```
If moncol >= 12 and moncol <=14 then
     'Do nothing
else
     'delete code
end if
```